# Merging Similar Arrays, PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this array based on a query that I made:

```
array(5) {
  [1] => array(5) {
    ["user_id"] => int(659)
    ["auth_id"] => string(28) "uhhuhhoney"
    ["username"] => string(10) "MarkH"
    ["avatar_date"] => int(1374525025)
    ["gravatar"] => string(0) ""
  }
  [2] => array(5) {
    ["user_id"] => int(326)
    ["auth_id"] => string(9) "rabits"
    ["username"] => string(9) "HankHill"
    ["avatar_date"] => int(1398866942)
    ["gravatar"] => string(0) ""
  }
  [3] => array(5) {
    ["user_id"] => int(326)
    ["auth_id"] => string(28) "identity_iml"
    ["username"] => string(9) "HankHill"
    ["avatar_date"] => int(1398866942)
    ["gravatar"] => string(0) ""
  }
  [4] => array(5) {
    ["user_id"] => int(1)
    ["auth_id"] => string(28) "barney"
    ["username"] => string(12) "Alice"
    ["avatar_date"] => int(1407362848)
    ["gravatar"] => string(0) ""
  }
  [5] => array(5) {
    ["user_id"] => int(1)
    ["auth_id"] => string(28) "a65s564sfad56654fsad"
    ["username"] => string(12) "Alice"
    ["avatar_date"] => int(1407362848)
    ["gravatar"] => string(0) ""
  }
}
```

I want to be able to combine any entries that have the same user_id, which would end up combining the array key 'auth_id'. Now I'm a bit confused as to if it's possible via MySQL or PHP.

I attempted to try and combine similar via MySQL using the GROUP_CONCAT function but it just merged every auth_id to a single row.

The query is the following:

```
SELECT mumble.*, user.username, user.avatar_date, user.gravatar,
GROUP_CONCAT(mumble.auth_id)
FROM xf_mumble AS mumble
LEFT JOIN xf_user AS user ON (user.user_id = mumble.user_id)
ORDER BY mumble.user_id DESC, user.username
```

If it's not possible via MySQL then how could I do it effectively via PHP since I can't think of a good way to do it. I was thinking the following:

```
$results = array();

for (new $i = 0, $i < sizeof($query), $i++)
{
    if (array_key_exists($query[$i - 1]) && $query[$i - 1]['user_id'] = $query[$i]['user_id'])
    {
        $results[$i]['auth_id'][] = $query[$i]['auth_id'];
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query needs a `group by`:

```
SELECT mumble.*, user.username, user.avatar_date, user.gravatar,
       GROUP_CONCAT(mumble.auth_id)
FROM xf_mumble AS mumble LEFT JOIN
     xf_user AS user
     ON (user.user_id = mumble.user_id)
GROUP BY mumble.user_id, user.username
ORDER BY mumble.user_id DESC, user.username
```

Comment: And then (this may be obvious, but just to be clear), use `explode`, e.g. `explode(',', $query[$i]['auth_id'])`

Comment: What exactly is the 'group by' addition doing that fixes the issue?

Comment: @EllisonPatterson . . . You are using the aggregation function `group_concat()`.  Without a `group by`, MySQL will return exactly one row -- the concatenation over all matching rows.  You seem to want one row per `user_id`, which is why there is a `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this? `query` is array you show

```
$results = array();
foreach ($query as $result) {
    $results[$result['user_id']][] = $result['auth_id'];
}
```

result will be:

```
array (3) {
    [659] => array(1) {
        [0] => string(10) "uhhuhhoney"
    }
    [326] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(6) "rabits"
        [1] => string(12) "identity_iml"
    }
   [1] => array(2) {
       [0] => string(6) "barney"
       [1] => string(20) "a65s564sfad56654fsad"
   }
}
```